# Count(*) to return 0 if no results for this query

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get 0 for this query when no results in DB. If no such bookings of this day at any time, it returns 0

```
SELECT datetime, COUNT(id) bookings
FROM booking 
WHERE datetime LIKE '2014-05-20%' 
OR datetime LIKE '2014-05-21%' 
OR datetime LIKE '2014-05-24%' 
GROUP BY datetime
```

I tried this but nothing, the same results:

```
SELECT datetime, IFNULL(COUNT(id), 0) bookings 
FROM booking 
WHERE datetime LIKE '2014-05-20%' 
OR datetime LIKE '2014-05-21%' 
OR datetime LIKE '2014-05-24%' 
GROUP BY datetime
```

I tried IFNULL(), and COALESCE() but still getting the same result. Please help with this query.

Result that I want:

```
+-----------------------+
| datetime  || bookings |
+-----------------------+
|2014-05-20 ||    5     |
|2014-05-21 ||    4     |
|2014-05-24 ||    0     |
+-----------------------+
```

I think is better select datetime one by one.

Comment: I definitely have no idea what you're talking about. Perhaps word it better?

Comment: use group by id instead of datetime

Comment: GROUP BY id the same result

Comment: `LIKE` is for comparing Strings (characters). It does not make any sense on (real) timestamp columns.

Comment: What do you mean by 'get 0'? Does it mean that if there is no id in a datetime, and then bookings will be 0?

Comment: If no such bookings of this day at any time, it returns 0

Comment: Please show some sample data, and the result that you want.

Comment: Simply select the result into a variable/temporary table, and then if that variable is null, select 0 instead.

Comment: use according to your date time column... WHERE datetime IN (2014-05-20,2014-05-21,2014-05-24)  or WHERE date(datetime) IN (2014-05-20,2014-05-21,2014-05-24)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have no data on one of the date you are filtering there will be no row with that data, regardless of the `COUNT`, to avoid this it's possible to create a temp table with the date you want to filter and `OUTER JOIN` that to the data table, an example is

```
SELECT dt.DateTime, Count(b.id) bookings
FROM   (SELECT cast('20140520' as datetime) datetime
        UNION ALL
        SELECT cast('20140521' as datetime) 
        UNION ALL
        SELECT cast('20140524' as datetime) ) dt 
       LEFT  JOIN booking b ON dt.datetime = b.datetime
GROUP BY dt.DateTime
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f97fb/10)